# How can I hold last frame of the video for several seconds with ffmpeg

Tags: video, filter, ffmpeg

I want to hold last frame of the video for some more seconds so that I can overlay another video on it with ffmpeg.

I have tried

- extracting last frame
- make it last some seconds
- and concatenating it with video.

This works fine, although when I test on Android overlay video freezes and I believe the reason must be the static image because I also tried overlaying video on a static image and had the same problem.

Now I was thinking maybe I could just hold the last frame of the video with ffmpeg?

Here is the command

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -loop 1 -t 10 -i image.png -i overlay.mp4 -filter_complex [0:v][1:v]concat[a];[2:v]pad=1280.0:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setpts=PTS+7/TB[b];[a][b]blend=all_mode='addition':all_opacity=1,format=yuva422p10le -y output.mp4
```

Comment: Shouldn't need to do anything. If the overlay video is longer than the base video, then the base video will freeze on its last frame and the overlay video will play out till its end. -- Use the overlay filter, not blend.

Comment: but I want overlay video to start at the end of base video. I use setpts=PTS+7/TB for that

Comment: Start it on the last frame of base video. If base video is 25 fps, setpts for overlay should be `PTS+6.96/TB`

Comment: it does not work. it stops when base video ends